# Saving settings data

Tags: android

Could anyone suggest the best way to save settings data? I want that user would find everything he changed during last time he used app. At the moment I am reading from sav.bin file placed in res/raw directory, but is it possible to access this file and write inside it?

Comment: You can not write to resources or assets, but you can write files anywhere else: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). They are no more than a key - value storage.

You can find all the details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: is there any way to use SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); in  (ScrollTextView) argument?